# Replace string and insert a character at a certain position in the same field

Tags: awk, sed

Hi I'm trying to replace `\_\_SEC\_\_00` with `$6$` and insert a `$` after the 19 character in that certain field.

Data:

```
Avivit Katzir,avivit,\_\_SEC\_\_00wLaxAKg1ecw80jGW0ACTr.kI5gttGo/YxHHUOeCZzDn8.3yFyPqJSKwXXYfBVPjco7RKPjK/1XBvYQAXC4jKm9pt8G6WtMrIRs0Lp/,demo,demo,demo
```

Expected output:

```
Avivit Katzir,avivit,$6$wLaxAKg1ecw80jGW$0ACTr.kI5gttGo/YxHHUOeCZzDn8.3yFyPqJSKwXXYfBVPjco7RKPjK/1XBvYQAXC4jKm9pt8G6WtMrIRs0Lp/,demo,demo,demo
```

I tried this command:

```
sed -e 's/\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_../\$6\$/' -e 's/./&\$/19'
```

But I have a problem in inserting `$`.

Comment: if you are trying to convert the hashes from the Houzz data dump, your forumula is off. They don't all start with \_\_SEC\_\_00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a capturing group there.

```
sed -E 's/\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_..(.{16})/$6$\1$/'
```

Answer (score 2):

In `awk`, with shown samples could you please try following, based on your shown samples written in GNU `awk`. You could change from `\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_00` to `\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_..` in case you want to match any characters here.

```
awk '
match($0,/\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_00/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "$6$"\
  substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH,16)"$"\
  substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+16)
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/\\_\\_SEC\\_\\_00/){         ##using match function of awk here to match regexp \\_\\_SEC\\_\\_00, notice double \\ to escape \ here.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "$6$"\   ##Printing sub string from 1st index of line to just before 1 index of matched pattern then printing $6$
  substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH,16)"$"\     ##Printing sub string after matched part till next 16 characters here thne printing $ here.
  substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+16)         ##Printing rest of the line from here.
}' Input_file                          ##mentioning Input_file here.
```